# ggplot not plotting boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm a little new to R and very new to ggplot but I've encountered an issue with geom_boxplot():

I'm trying to draw boxplots of sequence length data, separated by sample type. The sequence lengths are all integers and the sample types have been stored as factors.
The command:

```
> ggplot(database, aes(x = SampleType, Y = Length), geom_boxplot())
```

draws a blank graph, with the appropriate X and Y axes, but no plots at all! So clearly it knows the limits of the Length variable (axes cutoffs are appropriate given my data) but is absolutely refusing to put boxplots on the graph!

Strangely, the command:

```
> ggplot(database) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = SampleType, Y = Length))
```

works!

I've tested ggplot on other datasets and both commands work fine, so its clearly just a problem with me!

I was hoping someone could tell me the difference between the two syntaxes, and potentially why one works when the other doesn't?

Thanks!

Comment: your syntax is wrong in your first example - you want `ggplot(df, aes(...)) + geom_boxplot()`

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to think about the construction of `ggplot2` graphics is to think of an overhead projector and layering (as each geom is a layer) geoms as transparency sheets.

`ggplot()` turns on the projector but sets no defaults for any layer (transparency sheet)

`ggplot(data = <some.data.frame>)`  would turn on the projector and set
`some.data.frame` as the default data source for the forthcoming layers.

`ggplot(data = <some.data.frame>, mapping = aes())` would turn on the
projector and set the default data set and aesthetics for each layer.

At this point, no layers (geoms) have been created or plotted.  In the `ggplot` call, the `...` allows for additional arguments to be passed, however, they are ignored. This is why your

> ggplot(database, aes(x = SampleType, Y = Length), geom_boxplot())

did not error, nor produce expected results.

The code block

```
ggplot(database, aes(x = SampleType, y = Length)) +
geom_boxplot()
```

will turn on the project, set the default data set to `database` and the default aesthetics. We then add on the layer `geom_boxplot`,as if a transparency sheet was placed on the overhead projector, to show the boxplots.

Comment: Thanks!! This is extremely helpful!! Not only did you answer my question but also helped me understand the machinations of ggplot! :) Appreciate it!